# mpdf bootstrap progress bar

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mpdf

i have a problem with a pdf export with mpdf, i doesn't show the bootstrap progress bars.

FYI: the final "a href" is there because i get this code via AJAX. So I store the PDF on the server and then the user can download it. I think is fine this way.

But my main problem is with respect to the bootstrap progress bars. 
The width of the bar is given by the length of the text, and not the 80% of this example

[image: progress bar]

My code is the following

```
$html = '<h2 class="text-success text-center underline">Indicadoresa</h2>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%"><b>Zona</b></td>
                <td>'.$s1.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Responsable</b></td>
                <td>'.$s0.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Periodo</b></td>
                <td>'.$s3.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Fecha/Hora Ingreso</b></td>
                <td>'.$s2.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Dotacion Total Zona</b></td>
                <td>'.$s4.'</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
         <h3 class="text-success text-center">Indicadores de Personal</h3>
            <h4 class="text-primary">Calificaciones</h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%"><b>Cantidad evaluaciones al rol de calificadores</b></td>
                    <td>'.$s5.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Cantidad evaluaciones sin Observaciones</b></td>
                    <td>'.$s6.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>% Evaluaciones sin Observaciones </b></td>
                    <td><div class="progress active" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="'.$s7.'">
                            <span>'.$s7.'</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';

require_once __DIR__ . '/plugins/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF('c');

$stylesheet  = '';
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents('dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output($s1.' Indicadores Anuales_'.$s3.' '.$s0.'.pdf','F');



?>
<h5 class="text-primary no-print">PDF</h5>
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped no-print" style="width:100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%"><b>Descargar</b></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $s1.' Indicadores Anuales_'.$s3.' '.$s0.'.pdf'?>" target="_blank">Descargar</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```